# Is there any build-in function in VBScript to repeat a string N-times?

Tags: string, vbscript, repeat

There is a function in VBScript `String(number,character)` returns a string that contains a repeating character of a specified length. E.g.:

```
String(5, "A")     ' output: "AAAAA"
```

Is there any function to repeat a string? E.g.:

```
RepeatString(5, "Ab")     ' output "AbAbAbAbAb"
```

Comment: In what context are you using the VBScript? There is nothing built in but you could declare a function of your own to do this.

Comment: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#VBScript

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I think you should extract the portion of code that refers to VBScript and post it as an answer (with the link for reference)

Comment: @VictorMoraes: I would, but Alex was quicker. I think his answer is enough. I was looking for a dupe, and did not focus on answering in the first place.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your link offers two approaches whilst Alex only has one, but yeah, maybe it's enough

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, nothing built in. Instead:

```
n      = 5
str    = "Ab"
result = replace(space(n), " ", str)
```

Comment: Ingenious! `Replace(Space(3)," ","ha")`

Answer (score 3):

For a general simple solution

```vbs
Function RepeatString( number, text )
    Redim buffer(number)
    RepeatString = Join( buffer, text )
End Function
```

But if the text is short but the number of repetitions is high, this is a much faster solution

```vbs
Function RepeatString( ByVal number, ByVal text )
    RepeatString=""
    While (number > 0)
        If number And 1 Then 
            RepeatString = RepeatString & text
        End If 
        number = number \ 2 
        If number > 0 Then
            text = text & text 
        End If 
    Wend
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

For code brevity, the accepted answer is good. But the following function is literally 10 times as fast. And it's twice as fast as `RepeatString()`. It uses a little-known feature of `Mid` where it fills the remainder of a string buffer with a *repeating* pattern in one go...

```
Function Repeat$(ByVal n&, s$)
    Dim r&
    r = Len(s)
    If n < 1 Then Exit Function
    If r = 0 Then Exit Function
    If r = 1 Then Repeat = String$(n, s): Exit Function
    Repeat = Space$(n * r)
    Mid$(Repeat, 1) = s: If n > 1 Then Mid$(Repeat, r + 1) = Repeat
End Function
```

Comment: haven't done VBA in a while, so haven't kept up with the syntax, so this is fairly cryptic

Comment: No new syntax here. In fact this function would work in 1980's BASIC.

Comment: I haven't seen `String$(n, s)` before. What does it do? I thought it behaved similarly to  `Space$(n * r)`, but I am not able to find it in the Microsoft VBA docs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-function

Comment: VBScript does'nt have the mid$ statement

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to accomplish this using built-in excel formula REPT()

```
Function RepeatMyStringTimes()
    Const myString As String = "Some String"
    Const Times As Byte = 7
    Debug.Print Excel.WorksheetFunction.Rept("S", Times)
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

FYI I needed to have a 10-character string repeated more then 25 million times and the function Repeat$(ByVal n&, s$) took half a second to perform it, it saved my day! :)

Answer (score -1):

We can create a simple custom function like this

```
Function RepeatString(Byval AString As String, byval Times As Long)
    If AString = vbNullString Or Times < 0 Then RepeatString = CVErr(xlErrNA): Exit Function
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    For i = 1 To Times
        result = result & AString
    Next
    RepeatString = result
End Function
```

Or use [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-function) function to return repeating character strings of the length specified.

```
Dim MyString
MyString = String(5, "*")    ' Returns "*****".
MyString = String(5, 42)    ' Returns "*****".
MyString = String(10, "ABC")    ' Returns "AAAAAAAAAA".
```

Comment: You shouldn't copy/paste content from the internet without attribution. That is plagiarism.